# Excel calculation based on input from any cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need a column of numbers that are all generated based on the input of ANY of the cells.
Let's say I need each cell to be 50% of the previous one like so:

```
1000
500
250
125
```

I realize I can multiply based on the input of one designated input cell. In this scenario perhaps the first cell is the input cell, and the rest of them will be = input*0.5

The issue is that I would like to be able to use any cell as an input and ALL other cells will automatically change according to the same rules but based on that number. For instance, taking the above example, if I type 40 in place of 250, the resulting column would look like this:

```
160
80
40
20
```

Does this make sense? I appreciate any assistance on this!

Comment: A cell cannot contain both a formula and an input value.  You can use a formula to figure out the value for the cell based on other cells, but if you replace it with an input value, you lose the formula.  You can do this with VBA, but the simplest approach is to have the input separate from the results.

Answer (score 0):

### Without VBA

The closest you can do without VBA is by providing input and result column.

`=INDEX($A$1:$A$10, MATCH(FALSE, ISBLANK($A$1:$A$10), 0))*2^(MATCH(FALSE, ISBLANK($A$1:$A$10), 0)-ROW())`

Change `$A$1:$A$10` to your desired range, and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead of Enter when inserting this formula. You can autofill it.

Optional: put this data validation on your input range/column. Adapt the range to your need, but remember **the $ signs**. This will make the range only accept one input.

`=COUNTA($A$1:$A$3)<=1`

The result:

```
400  | 400*2^(1-1) => 400 | First non-blank value is 400
     | 400*2^(1-2) => 200 | First non-blank row number is 1, current row is 2
     | 400*2^(1-3) => 100 | Current row is 3

     | 300*2^(2-1) => 600 | First non-blank value is 300
300  | 300*2^(2-2) => 300 | First non-blank row number is 2, current row is 2
     | 300*2^(2-3) => 150 | Current row is 3
```

### Explanation

The formula takes the value of the first cell from input column (A) that is not blank (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29967410/find-first-non-blank-cell-in-a-range)). It is then multiplied with `2 powered by the row number of first non-blank cell minus current row number`.

### With VBA

Adapted from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/813639/excel-how-to-have-a-formula-output-and-user-input-on-the-same-cell?rq=1)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim InputRange As Range, cell As Range
Dim BaseValue As Double
Set InputRange = Range("B1:B4")

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
If Intersect(Target, InputRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

BaseValue = Target.Value*2^(Target.Row - InputRange.Row)

Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each cell In InputRange
 cell.Value = BaseValue
 BaseValue = BaseValue/2
Next cell
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Adapt your range on `Set InputRange = Range("B1:B4")`

### Explanation

```
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
If Intersect(Target, InputRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

Only change of one cell is evaluated. Only value change that is not because of delete operation is evaluated. Only change made within the InputRange is evaluated.

```
BaseValue = Target.Value*2^(Target.Row - InputRange.Row)
```

Establish the BaseValue, that is the value of the topmost cell of the range. This is done by multiplying the input value with 2 powered by the difference between topmost row and target row (example: if you input in B8 and the range covers B3:B9, then it multiply with `2 power (8-3)`)

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
...
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Prevents Events from triggering because of this following change.

```
For Each cell In InputRange
 cell.Value = BaseValue
 BaseValue = BaseValue/2
Next cell
```

Changes the value of each cell, starting from topmost of the defined range, to a proportion of the BaseValue.

Comment: A simpler non-VBA solution if you want to incorporate it: B1: `=A1+2*A2+4*A3+8*A4`;  B2: `=A1/2+A2+2*A3+4*A4`;  B3: `=A1/4+A2/2+A3+2*A4`; B4: `=A1/8+A2/4+A3/2+A4`. (question has four entries)

Answer (score 0):

In this example you can use one input cell (`C6`)
together with a helper cell (`B6`), where you need to put 
an index in a list of values: 
the input value will appear at that index position in a list.

The formula is just

```
=$C$6*$E$2^(D4-$B$6)
```

Note that the percent value is stored in `E2`.

Start with `1000` at `0` position:

[image]

Than change to `40` at position `2`:

[image]

You can also get rid of index column,
but I think it's handy to have it.