# Want the same cell to either display the value based on a formula or else allow user input, depending on the radio button chosen

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros, microsoft-excel-365

I have cell (C17) whose value should depend on the choices made via radio buttons. One button is called 'defaults' and other button is 'custom'. The thing is, when I select the 'custom' button, I want the cell C17 to allow a user input. However, this will delete any formula in that cell. **What I'd like is to be able to select the 'custom' button and enter my own value in the cell, but if I switch to 'defaults', I'd like the value displayed in the same cell to be based on a formula.**

Additional note: this cell value will also be referenced in other formulas (I hope this doesn't change how the above functionality is implemented, but just wanted to note). I believe VBA may need to used, but so far I haven't done it (the radio buttons are just form controls).

I saw this post, but isn't exactly the same: [EXCEL - How to have a formula output and user input on the same cell?](https://superuser.com/questions/813639/excel-how-to-have-a-formula-output-and-user-input-on-the-same-cell)

Comment: in short you can't.  The only option is to have another cell in which the user inputs their data then using an IF in the cell, it will choose either the formula or the value in the user entered cell.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the option buttons do not activate a change event in the page, you would need to link these macros to the correct option buttons:

```
Sub Opt1()

Sheet1.Range("C17").Formula2 = "=A2 * 2"

End Sub
Sub Opt2()

Sheet1.Range("C17").Formula2 = Empty

End Sub
```

The above need to be placed in the sheet code then use assign macro for the option buttons.

Changed to reflect comment below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C30")) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target.Value
            Case 1
        Range("C17").Formula2 = "=$A2 * 2"
            Case 2
        Range("C17").Value = Empty
    End Select
End If
End Sub
```

The above code goes in the sheet code for the sheet where the change will occur.

You can use a single button (this code assumes a form button, not activex), just change the sheet reference and formula to suit.

```
Sub CVal()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet1

If ws.Range("C17").Formula2 = "=$A2 * 2" Then
ws.Range("C17").Value = Empty
ws.Shapes(Application.Caller).TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Defaults"
Else
ws.Range("C17").Formula2 = "=$A2 * 2"
ws.Shapes(Application.Caller).TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Custom"
End If

End Sub
```

If you want to use two buttons just tease the code from the if statement into the two separate buttons.

NB: the code goes in a module not the sheet code.
Justin

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! 
I am not understanding the single button version, and new to VB so need help with two button version:
I'd like to be able to switch back and forth by clicking the 'defaults' and 'custom' radio buttons which are located on another cell on the sheet. I can assign these buttons to one group, so I could keep a cell (say C30), whose value is either 1 or 2 depending on which radio button is chosen. So it now boils down to getting my target cell C17 to now either allow user input or display the result of a formula on another cell, based on whether C30 is 1 or 2.

Comment: Sorry for the brevity on the above post, due to word limits. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Gman, I am assuming you know how to insert the code into the sheet? Let me know how this one goes.

Comment: Hi Justin, I assume that I only need to paste the edited code (the first snippet, not the second one?). I just added that first one to the 'sheet' code after Option Explicit and pressed Alt+Q, saved it as a .xlsm file and reopened it, but the code doesn't seem to be doing anything to the target cell (B17 in the actual case). I included my reference cell which changes its value from 1 to 2 (the C30 equivalent in the example I gave) based on radio buttons, but even then nothing seems to change in my target cell B17. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong; thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Hi Gman, sorry about that I just checked using the option buttons (form control) and for some reason they do not activate a change event for the page, and even stop manual changes activating. If you want to stick to the option buttons then you need to link some code to them as in the answer above, alternatively you can change to data validation list on your front page rather than option buttons, which would activate the change event. Then put sheet names in front of the ranges and change the CASE statements for the existing sheet change event, let me know if you want to try this route.